# Testing Angular with karma, file ordering

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I've been struggling with my karma file load order for a while now, this is the file config for my karma.config.js:

```
files: [
            'bower/angular/angular.js',
            'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'src/**/*.module.js',
            'src/**/*.js',
            'tests/**/*.js'
        ],
```

The 2 files I actually want to test are my module under `src/main/main.module.js` and my main controller under `src/main/main.controller.js`.

This is my test config (under `tests/main/main.controller.spec.js`)

```
 var mockScope,
        controller,
        backend,
        mockInterval,
        mockTimeout;

beforeEach(angular.mock.module('main'));

beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $http, $interval, $timeout) {
    mockScope = $rootScope.$new();
    mockInterval = $interval;
    mockTimeout = $timeout;
    controller = $controller('mainCtrl', {
        $scope: mockScope,
        $http: $http,
        $interval: mockInterval,
        $timeout: mockTimeout
    });
}));
```

To the best of my knowledge this means that the loading order is as follows:

1. AngularJS
2. AngularJS dependent modules (angular-mocks)
3. My modules
4. My controllers, factories, directives, etc...
5. My test files

However when running this I get the following error: `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'mainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined` which probably happens at the moment I want to instantiate my controller in my test file.

The weird thing is, that when I change the controller name to something that comes later than `main.module.js` alphabetically, for example to `xxx.controller.js` everything works just fine. According to the karma documentation:

> Multiple files matching a single pattern are sorted alphabetically.

This led me to believe that both my controller and module got matched to the pattern `src/**/*.js`. However the docs also state that:

> Each file is included exactly once. If multiple patterns match the same file, it's included as if it only matched the first pattern.

So this shouldn't even happen, my module matches both patterns but since the module pattern is listed above the controller pattern it should match the earlier declared pattern and therefore be loaded before the controller.

When I check the network tab it baffled me to find out that the load ordering is actually fine (as in module > controller > test) and is completely the same as when I change the filename to something that comes after the module.

I run karma from the root of my project with the following command: `karma start karma.config.js`

My karma version is 0.13.0

Comment: have you tried to exclude module files from `src/**/*.js`?

Comment: @hansmaad I've just tried this `'src/**/*.js(!*.module.js)'`, but that didn't work, thought that might not be the right way to exclude module

Comment: have your tried src/**/*.controller.js in place of src/**/*.js

Comment: @MaheshSapkal I did and that works indeed, however that doesn't fix the core of my problem. When I will want to test factories, directives, etc.. it would be silly to add a pattern for each of those

Comment: Yeah I know, but the only solution I can think of is to load the controller, factories, directives all with a separate pattern.

Comment: @MaheshSapkal I honestly doubt that, according to karma's doc a file that matches two patterns will just be treated as if it matched the first pattern, so my current order shouldn't cause any problems

Comment: Got this as well.
I can confirm that specifying the file and then using the globing expression actually includes it TWICE. This is a bug introduced in karma 0.13.0, see https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1499 "app/scripts/elportalapp.js",<br/>
"app/scripts/\*\*/\*.js",<br/>
"test/mock/\*\*/\*.js",<br/>
"test/spec/\*\*/\*.js"<br/> **'/base/app/scripts/elportalapp.js': '2297e40af2d6c5cf6b06a355d867c3875bd39b1f'**, '/base/app/scripts/controllers/aceselector.js': '158b2c676e2f19db05248efdc07f3d713275aa40', '/base/app/scripts/controllers/admin.js': 'fd0988775454ae5828b034c767db647b09806e3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just released `v0.13.1` with a fix that should resolve this issue, please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: It works now with the configuration in my original post, thanks for resolving this so quickly :)

Comment: Has this regressed? I'm having a similar issue where I exclude a file (no serve/include/watch) which is later caught by a glob pattern and is indeed served up. This was ok in the last version of Karma 0.12

Answer (score 0):

Like @hansmaad said I eventually found the glob pattern to exclude module from my controller pattern so changing `src/**/*.js`, to `'src/**/!(*.module)*.js'` worked for me. Thought the earlier solution should also work according to karma's documentation. Perhaps this is a bug in karma 0.13.0?

Answer (score 0):

try this way.

```
files: [
            'bower/angular/angular.js',
            'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js', 
            'src/**/*.js',
            'tests/**/*.js'
        ],
```

Comment: I tried that before, but this doesn't work for obvious reasons: both module and controller match the pattern, but any files which come before the module (alphabetically) will be loaded first which won't work with angular